# Dynamically defining a controller for use in callback in an ActiveMethod concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm trying to DRY up a bunch of the controllers we are using.

I have an `ActiveSupport::Concern` that I'm trying to dynamically create a class in. So in the `include do` block I've added a definitions of the action:

```
module MyFancyMixin
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
  def new
    self.target= self.class.target_type.new
  end
end
end
```

I include this in an ApplciationController with

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
   include MyFancyMixin
end
```

However, the "new" never gets called on the action...I'm guessing I need to tell something to the router or something, but I'm at a loss. Can one define actions in a Concern? How do you get it to call the "new" correctly?

Comment: just remove included at all, simply define new inside your module.

Comment: @BroiSatse nice. Can you package that into an answer and explain why it doesn't work in the "include do"? There isn't really anything out there that explains what needs to go in the include do and what can't. I'm guessing it is just the things that need the class to be defined first (events, any fancy parsing of the class name you do, ect) but I don't have any idea why the `include do` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply to that. Could you post your controller, i.e. how you include it to your controller?

Comment: @BroiSatse its actually the same way as above...with my fancy mixin most controllers only need to define more stuff if they need to override preprogrammed behavior.

Comment: Interesting. I did some testing and it seems that there is very little difference between defining a method in and out of included block.  Do you define new method within controller as well?